# Error Relating to AppTranslocation in macOS Sierra

Tags: applescript, macos-sierra

It would appear that Gatekeeper in macOS Sierra is a bit pickier. At any rate, it is causing a small utility I made some years ago to throw a rather annoying error.

As I haven't yet had the time to dig into the under-the-hood changes in Sierra, I'm not sure how to fix the error. Does anyone have experience dealing with errors relating to AppTranslocation and fixing them?

Code and error follow:

**Code**:

```
tell application "Finder"
set currentDir to POSIX path of ((container of (path to me)) as text)
end tell
set currentDir to quoted form of currentDir
set lib80211 to quoted form of "AirPort Utility 5.6.1 Launcher.app/Contents/Resources/Apple80211.framework/Versions/A/Apple80211"

do shell script "export DYLD_INSERT_LIBRARIES=" & currentDir & lib80211 & "
cd " & currentDir & "AirPort\\ Utility\\ 5.6.1.app/Contents/MacOS
./AirPort\\ Utility"
```

**Error**:

```
sh: line 1: cd: /private/var/folders/t4/7k5z832d2tjd4xpzvvq43n4m0000gn/T/AppTranslocation/23AF67A4-3DF7-4982-A1A3-B019CDACB4C2/dAirPort Utility 5.6.1.app/Contents/MacOS: No such file or directory
sh: line 2: ./AirPort Utility: No such file or directory (127)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, after a fairly significant amount of trial and error (and a bit of reading about how AppTranslocation works in macOS 10.12 Sierra), I've discovered a fix.

In essence, you have to open the *.dmg and then *move* the contents to some other folder in Finder. The catch: If you move both simultaneously, AppTranslocation may 'tag' them (seemingly permanently) and continue to run *every* time you try to launch either *.app); this seems like a bug, and I intend to report it to Apple.

**The Solution**

Re-download the *.dmg (as others have stated) **and** move the two files it contains *one at a time* into a folder (preferably Utilities, but it's up to you where you want them to reside). Once you've done this, run the Launcher and everything should work as before.

Comment: I was retrieving the 2 files from a time machine backup and had quite a rough time getting it to work, but thanks to your suggestion I moved the files around a bit and finally it worked!

Answer (score 1):

You have to download once again Airport Utility Launcher from the dev website, because when you install macOS Sierra it erase the Airport Utility 5.6.1. that's why you have to download the whole folder from the website :http://zcs.zyniker.org/airport-utility-v5-6-1/

Hope it helps.

Comment: In this case, I *am* the developer. Unfortunately, I haven't had time to look into what changed with Gatekeeper in Sierra, so I haven't been able to update the Launcher. I would like to get an update out so that people who have been using the Launcher will not be left out in the cold by updating to Sierra.