# Adobe Air App unable to load assets after download on Mac OS Sierra

Tags: air, adobe, macos-sierra

After downloading, unzip and start my App and click ok for "app downloaded from internet" warning the App starts. But the App does not load any assets from subfolders.

I can make it work if I copy the App to an other folder and back again.

I have this problem on Mac OS Sierra only. Using older Mac OS and Windows everything works as expected.

Comment: Could you please share your directory structure? Also try adding as much code and data as possible.

Comment: It is only one app File, asset folder and xml config file.
PresentationFolder
- pres.app
- presConfig.xml
- presAssetsFolder

If i copy pres.app to an other folder and back again it works.
Looks like the system is not removing com.apple.quarantine attribute

Comment: Please share a code sample in which your app does not load assets, and your config.xml file, and a screenshot of your app folder and its directories.

Answer (score 0):

When using Sierra, you therefore have to drag the app from a disk image to a location such as /Applications before trying to run it. The same applies to Zip and other archives, or apps downloaded to your Downloads folder. Once you have moved the app in the Finder, it will not be translocated by Gatekeeper.

[macOS Sierra will break many installers and updaters](https://eclecticlight.co/2016/06/16/macos-sierra-will-break-many-installers-and-updaters/)

[AppTranslocation in MacOS Sierra](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39658199/error-relating-to-apptranslocation-in-macos-sierra)